# Conjugate Harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis

$\displaystyle u=\frac{1}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)$ is harmonic and find its harmonic conjugate function

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$

$\displaystyle dv=\int\frac{-\partial u}{\partial y}dx  +\int\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dy$

then

$\displaystyle v= \tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x} - \tan^{-1}\frac{x}{y} +c$

What did I do wrong here ?

Comment: this might be helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/857712/show-that-displaystyle-u-frac12-logx2y2-is-harmonic-and-find-its-ha

Answer (score 1):

$$\displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$$

One of the Cauchy-Riemann equations is:

$$\displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$

so

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$$

$$v = \int \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} \, dy=\frac{1}{x} \int  \frac{1}{1+(\frac{y}{x})^2} \,dy= \tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x} + \text{const.} $$
Similarly,
$$v =- \int \frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \, dx=- \tan^{-1} \frac{x}{y} + \text{const.} $$

Since $\tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x} $ and $  - \tan^{-1} \frac{x}{y}$ differ by a constant $(|\tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x} +\tan^{-1} \frac{x}{y}| = \frac{\pi}{2})$, either answer is acceptable.

Comment: that i know... just want to ask whether the expression that i wrote for dv can be written or not

Comment: No, cannot.  You have written an expression that is twice $dv$.

Comment: The above comment should say "twice $v$".